# What causes Unused global option(s) error after updating to latex-base 2022-06-01-PL1?

Tags: latex-base, doc

After applying today's kernel updates (2022-06-01-PL1) it seems loading the `doc` package now causes an Unused global option(s) warning over options passed to the `article` document class that was not there yesterday. The warning disappears if `doc` is not loaded. I checked the changelog and the GitHub repos for issues related to this and found nothing. I understand warnings are sometimes harmless but this one was not happening prior to the referenced update. Cursory inspection indicates the final document is fine.

Note that the warning message is strangely formatted as it contains duplicates of the options passed to `article`.

From the log:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [10pt,letterpaper,10pt,letterpaper].
```

MWE:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{doc}

\begin{document}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's a side effect of the changes to support the new keyval option handling, but we can probably tweak that a bit more, let me try it with the PL1 release...

Comment: can you raise at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue in a recent change: I overdid the 'code reuse'. A fix and a second PL will address this within a day or two.

Comment: Noted, and thank you.

Comment: Alas the problem persists as of today's update, with each option now appearing thrice instead of twice in the warning message. Something else must be going on.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I've just double-checked and the example runs fine here: you might have another package loaded which has a related issue that I'm about to send a fix for to CTAN.

Comment: Yes indeed. Mea culpa! Something else is going on. I'm compiling the mandi .dtx file that uses tcolorbox extensively for documentation. I'll wait for the next fix. Sorry.

Comment: Just a note that today's update seemed to have fixed the issue.