# Unused global option(s) warning with latex 2022-06-01-PL2

Tags: warnings, latex-base, l3keys

*I was about to ask this question a few days ago, but at the time the site suggested [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648195/194994) to me and I thought that it is the same problem with mine. But now as PL2 releases, the problem in the addressed question is fixed yet mine remain, hence the question below.*

Suppose that there is a package like the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {testpackage}
  {2022/06/20} {}
  {A test package}

\keys_define:nn { testpackage }
  {
    , unknown         .code:n             = {}
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { testpackage }

\endinput
```

And the main document is like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{testpackage}

\begin{document}

Text in case of empty.

\end{document}
```

Two days ago with 2022-06-01 PL1 one shall get

```
Unused global option(s):
    [11pt,11pt].
```

Now with PL2 it is:

```
Unused global option(s):
    [11pt].
```

However, in the previous releases, with `unknown.code:n = {}`, it is expected that there shouldn't be any warning here.

What is the problem here and how should one fix this?

Comment: Try without l3keys2e and with \ProcessKeyOptions (without the s in the middle)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That leads to `Missing \begin{document}`.

Comment: Oh and remove the argument (or make it an optional argument)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, now there's no problem. So should I do this to all my packages/classes? (I don't quite understand what is going on here, so not sure if it applies to all cases)

Comment: @Jinwen sorry about the bug, PL2 fixes it for the new version, looks like l3keys2e would need a similar fix, but that package should be considered legacy now, the new built in option code is based on the same core expl3 code but extended and improved so hopefully all packages using l3keys2e will switch

Comment: I'm now getting unused options in triplicate with the same warning message. I'm not using l3keys2e at all that I know of. Very strange.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL It may not be you, but the packages that you've loaded. For example, after having fixed all my classes and packages (to stop using `l3keys2e`), I discovered that the remaining warning in my document was caused by `scontents`, for which I'm not able to do much. Each package that uses `l3keys2e` can lead to a replication of your class options in the warning message.

Comment: Yes I just discovered that! Mea culpa! Something else is going on. I'm compiling a large .dtx project.

Comment: @Jinwen I think I have the packages isolated now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jinwen does the answer to this question answer your question? If so, can you accept it so we can get it out of the unanswered queue? If not, maybe clarify what is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `l3keys2e` in which I copied some (incorrect) code from an improvement to the new keyval handler in the kernel. On reflection, I've backed out the change in `l3keys2e` as the better plan is to migrate to the new kernel code. I will sort out a CTAN update later today to address this issue.

Comment: Thank you for fixing this. For now there are quite a lot packages that use `l3keys2e`, such as `unicode-math`, `embrac`, and big bundle like `ctex` uses it twice. Currently each instance of `l3keys2e` can lead to a replication of the global options in the warning message. Not sure how long it will take before they can all switch to the new option-setting method, especially if this new method requires a fairly new kernel, which might lead to compatibility issue.

Comment: @Jinwen I'll have the fix at CTAN today, so by Friday at the latest that will propogate

Comment: @Jinwen To be clear, once the fix is out, there's no need for packages to update - things will continue to work with `l3keys2e`, it's just that over time migration would be useful (I've set this up as a conditional in `siunitx` for example)