# Is \ProcessKeysPackageOptions obsolete?

Tags: latex3, package-options

I read in the `l3keys2e` documentation that this package was obsolete.

What is the new way of dealing with package options? At the moment, I'm using `\ProcessKeysPackageOptions`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we have integrated into the kernel a very slightly modified method:

```
\ProcessKeyOptions [ <family> ]
```

There is no 'just the package' command in the kernel, as this behaviour did not match that of the 'classical' `\ProcessOptions` command.

Comment: By 'no "just the package" command' do you just mean there's no command to process just the options given for this package?

Comment: I mean there's not a direct equivalent of `\ProcessKeysPackageOptions`, only of `\ProcessKeysOptions`: we talked about this in the team, and the conclusion was that the options to `\documentclass` have always been intended to be global so packages should not just 'ignore' them .

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought you must mean, but wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: Is there a simple tutorial to migrate from the old style to the new one?

Comment: Here is a link talking about that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648584/as-of-2022-how-should-one-build-class-package-options-without-l3keys2e .