# Very basic question - cannot usepackage{chemformula}

Tags: installing, chemformula

I just made a new install of the latest MiKTeX distribution, then installed Texmaker, in this order.

Then I found that my tex file does not run, although it does so on Overleaf, and on another PC where I did exactly the same installation process.

I started to reduce the file to see what is working and what not. When I try to `\usepackage{chemformula}`, I get the error:

[image]

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{chemformula} 

\begin{document}

(Type your content here.)

\end{document}
```

The other packages work. Why just this one is not?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this related post about `\ProcessKeysPackageOptions`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/696680/36296

As a temporary hack, you could make the code compile by loading `\usepackage{l3keys2e}` before `chemformula`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chemformula} 

\begin{document}

(Type your content here.)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm, although I don't really get what the problem was!

Comment: @felisnigripes The problem is that the macro `\ProcessKeysPackageOptions` is obsolete. The `chemformula` package should replace it with the new version from the latex kernel. The obsolete `l3keys3e` package still has the old version and thus avoids the error you showed.